# If I use ControllerAs to use a controller twice on a page, how can the controller code tell WHICH one it's dealing with?

Tags: angularjs

***Complete noob*** with Angular and the fact that I am asking this question (to which I cannot find an answer after two days) suggests to me that I am approaching this all wrong :/

I am using the DatePicker controller twice on the same page. So I have:

```
    <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl as fromdate">
...
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl as todate">
...
    </div>
```

So in my js code for the controller, how do I know which datepicker has "called" it because I want to save the value in the appropriate (**from** or **to**)cookie?

```
 app.controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $log) {

     this.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
     this.format = this.formats[0];

     this.today = function() {
         this.value = new Date();
     };
     this.today();

     this.clear = function () {
         this.value = null;
     };


     this.opened = false;


     this.dpopen = function ($event) {
         $log.info("DPOpened " )
         $event.preventDefault();
         $event.stopPropagation();

         this.opened = true;
     };

        this.dateOptions = {
         formatYear: 'yy',
         startingDay: 1
     };
```

As I say, I expect I need to understand some simple point to do this right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 1

There are for me 2 options for doing this. The easiest one is to call a function of your controller inside `ng-init`.

add this into your controller :

```
var self = this;
this.isToOrFrom = function(toOrFrom){
    self.isTo = (toOrFrom === "to");
};
```

and call this from your template :

```
    <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl as date" ng-init="date.isToOrFrom('to')">
...
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl as date" ng-init="date.isToOrFrom('from')"">
...
    </div>
```

ps : [Angular does not recommend to use ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

- 2

The second option (the one I advice) is to wrap your controller into a directive, and add an additional parameter.

```
app.directive('datePicker', function(){
    return : {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope:{
            isToOrFrom: '@',
        },
        controller : function ($scope, $log) {

           this.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
           this.format = this.formats[0];

           this.today = function() {
               this.value = new Date();
           };
           this.today();

           this.clear = function () {
               this.value = null;
           };
           this.isTo = ($scope.isToOrFrom === "to");

           this.opened = false;


           this.dpopen = function ($event) {
               $log.info("DPOpened " )
               $event.preventDefault();
               $event.stopPropagation();

               this.opened = true;
           };

           this.dateOptions = {
               formatYear: 'yy',
               startingDay: 1
           };
      },
      controllerAs : 'date',
      template: '<div>add your template here</div>'

});
```

And then, you just have to use it like the following in your view :

```
<div date-picker is-to-or-from="to" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Jean-Philippe. I hadn't appreciated that this was possible and so takes me one step closer to my solution (I am now still trying to work out how to detect and pass the value of each into my cookies, but I must try and work that out myself before resorting to **another** question!)

Comment: I've never tried, but have a look at this, it looks pretty simple : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: @JohnEllis pay attention that a cookie is sent with every request to the server. If you want to store a value for later use, you maybe want to use localStorage